# Nodejs returns "out of memory" when converting a large XML to JSON using module "xml2json"

Tags: json, node.js, xml, xml-parsing

I have a 1.7GB XML file and I want to convert it into a JSON file. When I use "xml2json" module to parse it, it returns

> Error: There are errors in your xml file: out of memory

My code is:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const parser = require("xml2json");

const xmlObject = fs.readFileSync("./database1.xml")
const tempObject = JSON.parse(parser.toJson(xmlObject));
```

And this is the error:

```
throw new Error('There are errors in your xml file: ' + parser.getError());
    ^

Error: There are errors in your xml file: out of memory
```

I already add the parameter "--max-old-space-size=4096" when running the code but it doesn't work.

Is there any solution? Or could someone provide another way to convert a large XML into JSON file?
Thanks.

Comment: For this, you should use node-expat because its using streaming which would reduce the amount of memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

This flag "--max-old-space-size=4096" is correct.
Simply try to add more:

```
--max-old-space-size=8192
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried it but got the same error.

Comment: Try to remove some objects copying. `const tempObject = parser.toJson(xmlObject);`

Comment: I tried it again but still the same. I am reading the source file. I find this module uses another module called "node-expat" to parse xml file and the error comes from a function called "getError()" inside "node-expat". I guess it is a problem with this module but I have no idea of how to fix it yet. But thank you for your help again.